# How to SELECT rows with time duration stored in varchar column?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, php, time

There is a column in table defined like this :

```
duration varchar(10)
```

It has value for duration of a MP3 file stored in it like : **52:19**  (Minutes : Seconds)

How can I create a SQL query, for selecting rows with duration between **3:00 and 6:45** (i.e. SELECT songs neither too short nor too long)

***The database is hosted on some 3rd party server so I cannot modify table structure.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   * FROM table
WHERE (SUBSTRING_INDEX(duration,':',1)*60)+SUBSTRING_INDEX(duration,':',-1) 
BETWEEN 180 AND 405
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8cfe/40)

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) to isolate the minutes and seconds,convert minutes to seconds and add them up so the where condition has something to compare.Assuming all durations in the table have minutes and seconds separated by ':'

Comment: very short and simple answer . .that works (y)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a clean function for handling the conversion : [**TIME_TO_SEC**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)

For example, let's take your time from the question : `52:19`

```
mysql> select time_to_sec('52:19');
+----------------------+
| time_to_sec('52:19') |
+----------------------+
|               188340 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Wow, why is the number of seconds so high ? [**TIME_TO_SEC**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) interpreted it as 52 hours 19 minutes.

Let's try adding `00:` to the string

```
mysql> select time_to_sec('00:52:19');
+-------------------------+
| time_to_sec('00:52:19') |
+-------------------------+
|                    3139 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK, now that represents 52 min 19 seconds.

Since you are doing durations for MP3s, you will want format the string perfectly before running [**TIME_TO_SEC**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec). so that you handle durations over an hour and under a minute.

## SUGGESTION

Here is the query you need

```
SET @timetag = '52:19';
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(CONCAT(LEFT(tm,2),':',SUBSTR(tm,3,2),':',RIGHT(tm,2))) time_duration
FROM (SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(@timetag,':','')+1000000,6) tm) A;
```

Applying it against the table lloking for '3:00' and '6:45', here is that query

```
SELECT id,duration,other_info FROM
(SELECT *,TIME_TO_SEC(CONCAT(LEFT(tm,2),':',SUBSTR(tm,3,2),':',RIGHT(tm,2))) time_duration
FROM (SELECT *,RIGHT(REPLACE(duration,':','')+1000000,6) tm FROM mytable_durations) AA) A
WHERE time_duration BETWEEN TIME_TO_SEC('00:03:00') AND TIME_TO_SEC('00:06:45');
```

Here is some sample data

```
USE test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable_durations;
CREATE TABLE mytable_durations
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  duration VARCHAR(10),
  other_info VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO mytable_durations (duration,other_info) VALUES
('3:50','INFO 1'),('13:42','INFO 2'),('6:50','INFO 3'),
('6:45','INFO 4'),('13:50','INFO 5'),('3:50','INFO 6'),
('3:42','INFO 7'),('16:50','INFO 8'),('6:45','INFO 9'),
('3:50','INFO 10'),('23:50','INFO 11'),('5:50','INFO 12');
```

Let's load the sample data

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable_durations;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable_durations
    -> (
    ->   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   duration VARCHAR(10),
    ->   other_info VARCHAR(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.45 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO mytable_durations (duration,other_info) VALUES
    -> ('3:50','INFO 1'),('13:42','INFO 2'),('6:50','INFO 3'),
    -> ('6:45','INFO 4'),('13:50','INFO 5'),('3:50','INFO 6'),
    -> ('3:42','INFO 7'),('16:50','INFO 8'),('6:45','INFO 9'),
    -> ('3:50','INFO 10'),('23:50','INFO 11'),('5:50','INFO 12');
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable_durations;
+----+----------+------------+
| id | duration | other_info |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | 3:50     | INFO 1     |
|  2 | 13:42    | INFO 2     |
|  3 | 6:50     | INFO 3     |
|  4 | 6:45     | INFO 4     |
|  5 | 13:50    | INFO 5     |
|  6 | 3:50     | INFO 6     |
|  7 | 3:42     | INFO 7     |
|  8 | 16:50    | INFO 8     |
|  9 | 6:45     | INFO 9     |
| 10 | 3:50     | INFO 10    |
| 11 | 23:50    | INFO 11    |
| 12 | 5:50     | INFO 12    |
+----+----------+------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, let's run the query against the table

```
mysql> SELECT id,duration,other_info FROM
    -> (SELECT *,TIME_TO_SEC(CONCAT(LEFT(tm,2),':',SUBSTR(tm,3,2),':',RIGHT(tm,2))) time_duration
    -> FROM (SELECT *,RIGHT(REPLACE(duration,':','')+1000000,6) tm FROM mytable_durations) AA) A
    -> WHERE time_duration BETWEEN TIME_TO_SEC('00:03:00') AND TIME_TO_SEC('00:06:45');
+----+----------+------------+
| id | duration | other_info |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | 3:50     | INFO 1     |
|  4 | 6:45     | INFO 4     |
|  6 | 3:50     | INFO 6     |
|  7 | 3:42     | INFO 7     |
|  9 | 6:45     | INFO 9     |
| 10 | 3:50     | INFO 10    |
| 12 | 5:50     | INFO 12    |
+----+----------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Looks like it works.

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-12-23 12:34 EST

Since [**TIME_TO_SEC**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) cannot deal with minutes beyond 59, you need another comparison trick.

I have a more simplistic method

Remove the colon and compare the time like a decimal number

The query would be

```
SELECT * FROM mytable_durations WHERE REPLACE(duration,':','') BETWEEN 300 AND 645;
```

Here it is executed against the sample data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable_durations WHERE REPLACE(duration,':','') BETWEEN 300 AND 645;
+----+----------+------------+
| id | duration | other_info |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | 3:50     | INFO 1     |
|  4 | 6:45     | INFO 4     |
|  6 | 3:50     | INFO 6     |
|  7 | 3:42     | INFO 7     |
|  9 | 6:45     | INFO 9     |
| 10 | 3:50     | INFO 10    |
| 12 | 5:50     | INFO 12    |
+----+----------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: What if he has a duration bigger than one hour 66:10?

Comment: Ouch !!! `SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('66:10')` is 66 hours 10 minutes. `SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('00:66:10')` comes back NULL. Let me think this through.

Comment: Oh,BTW,this made me curious if time or date functions could be somehow used beyond their scope,>59 for time_to_sec.

Comment: Do you deal with MP3s with 3-digit minute durations such as `106:40` ???

Comment: Updated my answer with an entirely different approach.